# punctuation expected errors-c#

Tags: c#, punctuation

I am new to c#.I trıed to write basic average calculator.I get 60 error most of them

) expected

; expected

I checked but i think everythıng s correct.Can it be problem about that I use visual studio 2010?

```
using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Drawing;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Windows.Forms;

    namespace WindowsFormsApplication3
    {

            public partial class Form1 : Form
        {
            public Form1()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
            }

            private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                double a;
                a = ((Convert.ToInt16(textBox1.Text) * 0.4) + (Convert.ToInt16(textBox2.Text) * 0.6));
                if (a &gt;= 50 &amp; a &lt; 60 &amp; Convert.ToInt64(textBox2.Text) &gt;= 50)
                {
                    label4.Text = &quot;Ge&ccedil;ti&quot;;
                    label5.Text = &quot;CC&quot;;
                    textBox3.Text = a.ToString();
                }

                else
                {
                    label4.Text = &quot;KALDI&quot;;
                    label5.Text = &quot;FF&quot;;
                    textBox3.Text = a.ToString();            
                }

            }



                private void button2_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
                {
                textBox1.Text = &quot;&quot;;
                textBox2.Text = &quot;&quot;;
                textBox3.Text = &quot;&quot;;
                label4.Text = &quot;Durum&quot;;
                label5.Text = &quot;Sonuc&quot;;
                }


        }



        }
```

Comment: &quot;&quot;; ..? what are those things doing there?

Comment: Did you copy/paste this code from the web?

Comment: http://www.htmlescape.net/htmlunescape_tool.html

Answer (score 2):

You have HTML entities in the code, which you would have to convert back to real characters.

This for example:

```
if (a &gt;= 50 &amp; a &lt; 60 &amp; Convert.ToInt64(textBox2.Text) &gt;= 50)
```

should be:

```
if (a >= 50 & a < 60 & Convert.ToInt64(textBox2.Text) >= 50)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    double a;
    a = ((Convert.ToInt16(textBox1.Text) * 0.4) + (Convert.ToInt16(textBox2.Text) * 0.6));
    if (a >= 50 && a < 60 && Convert.ToInt64(textBox2.Text) >= 50)
    {
        label4.Text = "Ge&ccedil;ti";
        label5.Text = "CC";
        textBox3.Text = a.ToString();
    }
    else
    {
        label4.Text = "KALDI";
        label5.Text = "FF";
        textBox3.Text = a.ToString();            
    }
}

private void button2_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    textBox1.Text = "";
    textBox2.Text = "";
    textBox3.Text = "";
    label4.Text = "Durum";
    label5.Text = "Sonuc";
}
```